# Setting up ExpressJS with MongoDB on MERN Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

So when running Nodemon after setting up an ExpressJS & MongoDB client, I keep getting the

> "DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option {
>   useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor."

I'm not really sure where to insert this code into my server.js file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to insert it where you're creating your mongo connection.

For example (using `mongoose`)...

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { DATABASE } = process.env; // this a mongodb connection string that varies upon the NODE environment

const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true, // avoids DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated
  useCreateIndex: true, // avoids DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated.
  useFindAndModify: false, // avoids DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated.
  useUnifiedTopology: true // avoids DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated
};

mongoose.connect(DATABASE, options); // connect to our mongodb database
```

---

Here's a [Fullstack MERN boilerplate](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/database/index.js) I created and use for my projects, which has an [example of how to connect to a local mongo database](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/database/index.js). You can use it as a reference, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `mongodb` not `mongoose`, then only need to pass `{ useUnifiedTopology: true }` in your `MongoClient.connection` options:

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(client => {
    // do some stuff
  }).catch(error => {
    // do some stuff
  })
```

I hope it can help you.